# The open file operation failed issue in Python image compressing code using MAC OS M1 Chip

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library, image-compression

I am building a python script to compress the image on my M1 Macbook Air. But an error is coming

> The open file operation failed.

Below is the python code:

```
import PIL
from PIL import Image
from tkinter.filedialog import *

file_path = askopenfilename()
img = PIL.Image.open(file_path)
myHeight, myWidth = img.size

img = img.resize((myHeight, myWidth), PIL.Image.ANTIALIAS)
save_path = asksaveasfilename()

img.save(save_path+"_compressed.JPG")
```

Error screenshot

[image]

Screenshot of the error which came in the terminal

[image]

I have also imported the PILLOW.

Comment: Did you `print(file_path)` to see exactly what you got back?

Comment: Please run this in a terminal and provide the output _as text_, not as an image. Also, first make sure you have a [mcve]. As a new user here, further read [ask] and take the [tour]!

Comment: have you tried a different operating system ?

Comment: No, I only have macbook @D.L